# write a Query Unique ids with different city's

Tags: database

In A Table Cityid and CITYname  2 Columns:

```
city id  city name
1        Bang
1        hyd
1        pune
2        hyd
2        pune
2        chennai
```

I want the Result:

```
1 ---hyd,pune,bang(all citynames of city id)
2---
```

Answer (score 1):

You left off some key details required to answer your question:  What language are you using?

Here is the answer if you are using T-SQL on SQL Server 2005/2008:

Your Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cities](
    [cityid] [int] NULL,
    [cityname] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Your Data:

```
insert into cities(cityid,cityname)values(1,'Seattle')
insert into cities(cityid,cityname)values(1,'Portland')
insert into cities(cityid,cityname)values(2,'New York')
insert into cities(cityid,cityname)values(2,'Newark')
```

Your Query:

```
declare @result table(
    cityid int,
    cityname varchar(max)
)

declare @queue table(
    cityid int,
    cityname varchar(50)
)

declare @cityid int
declare @cityname varchar(50)

insert into @queue select * from cities

while(exists(select top 1 cityid from @queue)) begin
    select top 1 @cityid = cityid, @cityname = cityname from @queue
    if(exists(select cityid from @result where cityid = @cityid)) begin
        update @result
        set cityname = cityname + ', ' + @cityname
        where cityid = @cityid
    end else begin
        insert into @result(cityid,cityname) values(@cityid,@cityname)
    end
    delete from @queue where cityid = @cityid and cityname = @cityname
end

select * from @result
```

Your Result:

```
    cityid    cityname
1   1         Seattle, Portland
2   2         New York, Newark
```

Answer (score 0):

look up GROUP_CONCAT

or USER DEFINED AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS